# BLOCKCHAIN.INFO NO TRANSACTIONS

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info, lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet

Long story short. Can't see transactions from blockchain.info as blockchain.com is now the website.

Long story:
Created a miner in 2013. Mined it from BTC Gui... and had it sent to BLO.....IN.INFO was able to check my account via bloc...in.info .

One day, it went to zero.

I didn't know what to do. So I just assumed I lost it all.

Well. I logged on to the now BLO...IN.COM..... and it shows a zero balance. BUT WITH NO TRANSACTIONS.

I put in the mnemonic that I wrote down in 2013 to recover the wallet.... all it gives me is the PASSWORD... not the wallet ID. This is obviously a legacy wallet.

How do I recover this old account to see transactions from 2013?

Note:
I do not have wallet addresses from the miner to blo...ain.info
I do not have access to the miner

I want to see the transactions from 2013 and I want to try to see where this coin went just for peace of mind that I know it didn't just go to zero.

Thanks for any help.